# Can someone identify the make and model of my digital door lock?

Tags: lock, front-door

I have bought a new house with a digital door lock. The previous owner doesn't have any information or manual for the door lock and the lock code is very easy to guess.

Can someone identify the make and model of this door lock?

There is nothing written on the lock. I even tried to open the battery pack and couldn't find anything written there as well.

[image: Front]

[image: Back]

Comment: keep looking, it might be on the inside of the handle

Comment: Since it is wireless use Bluetooth to find it

Comment: I am not aware its wireless. You suggest the bluetooth name can give me the info? Can I also configure it using Bluetooth?

Comment: Using Bluetooth scan you might find it, then go on from there

Comment: is there anything written on the latch plate or the door edge?

Comment: @Ruskes - It could just as easily be Z-wave, Zigbee, or WiFi (though not likely given the age of that lock).

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned where in the world you are located. But if that door lock has any kind of wireless communication ability, and if that same model was offered for sale in the US or Canada (even if you're not in either of those places), then it'll have an FCCID and/or IC alphanumeric code somewhere on it. It's possible that these might be on a label in a battery compartment or on the reverse side of the hardware, ie pressed against the door. Tthere are web sites you can search with that code to learn more about the product including its make and model, and sometimes a copy of its manual.

Answer (score 0):

Dismount from the door and look for a label on the sides facing the door. If that doesn't help, this becomes a forensic dissection problem, and replacement may be cheaper than the man-hours to resolve the question.